# How to determine duration of .mid file in python?

Tags: python, audio, midi

Is there a way to determine the duration of an .mid file in python whether it be by examining the headers or by using an existing library?

Answer (score 5):

I verified that the Mido library works great on several tricky Type 0 and Type 1 files. http://mido.readthedocs.org/en/latest/midi_files.html

```
from mido import MidiFile
mid = MidiFile('testfile.mid')
print(mid.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi). I don't think it has a specific method that will tell immediately tell you what the duration is, but you should be able to calculate it based on the number of ticks and the tempo. Here's a rough example, but you'd have to play with the library a bit to see what the objects it gives you look like.

```
import midi
pattern = midi.read_midifile("mymidi.mid")
highest_tick = 0
for track in pattern:
    for tick in track:
        if tick['position'] > highest_tick:
            highest_tick = tick['position']

# duration = some math of tick * tempo
```

Comment: Hmm, i took a look at this before asking the question, I do not believe this project has any methods to get those values needed to calculate the duration.

Comment: I double checked the documentation and it appears like you should be able to, I added an example to give you an idea.

Comment: qwr suggested aubio.org, I'm not familiar with it but that may work better for you. Whichever library you use, the same idea applies.

Comment: The tempo can change during the song; you have to walk the whole file to calculate a duration. The Mido library offers a calculated length field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use something like [aubio.org](http://aubio.org/) to determine the last note.

Related: [How to calculate the time-length of a midi-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037534/how-to-calculate-the-time-length-of-a-midi-file)